# Antd dynamic form - how can I change form elements based on current values?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a dynamic Antd form where I can enter menu elements. The user can add, remove and reorder menu elements. The dynamic fields work fine, but I have a radio button for each dynamic element indicating that the corresponding menu element is an external URL or an internal page. I need to display different input elements if the user chooses URL or internal page. I tried the method listed in the Antd documentation, but it is for static fields and it doesn't seem to be working for dynamic elements.

My code so far is:

```
<Form.List name={"menuTree"}>
                {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                    <>
                        {fields.map((field, index) => (
                            <Row id={"menu-row-" + index} key={index}>
                                <Col span={8}>
                                    <Form.Item label="Title" name={[field.name, "title"]} key={"title" + index + Math.random()}>
                                        <Input />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                                <Col span={4}>
                                    <Form.Item label="Type" name={[field.name, "type"]}>
                                        <Radio.Group>
                                            <Radio value={"link"}>URL</Radio>
                                            <Radio value={"page"}>Page</Radio>
                                        </Radio.Group>
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                                <Col span={9}>
                                    <Form.Item
                                        // label="URL"
                                        // name={[field.name, "url"]}
                                        noStyle
                                        shouldUpdate={(prevValues, currentValues) => prevValues.type !== currentValues.type}>
                                        {({ getFieldValue }) => {
                                            return getFieldValue("type") === "link" ? (
                                                <Form.Item name={[field.name, "url"]} label="URL">
                                                    <Input />
                                                </Form.Item>
                                            ) : (
                                                <Form.Item name={[field.name, "page"]} label="Page">
                                                    <Input />
                                                </Form.Item>
                                            )
                                        }}
                                        <Input />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                                <Col span={2}>
                                    <Form.Item>
                                        <Button htmlType="button" onClick={() => moveUp(index)}>
                                            <CaretUpOutlined />
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button htmlType="button" onClick={() => moveDown(index)}>
                                            <CaretDownOutlined />
                                        </Button>
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                                <Col span={1}>
                                    <Button htmlType="button" onClick={() => removeMenuItem(index)}>
                                        <MinusOutlined />
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        ))}
                        <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => addMenuItem()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                            Add menu item
                        </Button>
                    </>
                )}
            </Form.List>
```

How can I achieve to change the input on a per line basis whenever the user changes the value of the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `type` value with wrong name path. `getFieldValue` expects the complete path when you want to get any value.

You form list name is `menuTree`. Since it's a list, your namepath will look like this:

`getFieldValue(['menuTree', field.name, 'type'])`

```
<Form>
    <Form.List name={'menuTree'}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
            <>
                {fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <Row id={'menu-row-' + index} key={index}>
                        <Col span={8}>
                            <Form.Item label='Title' name={[field.name, 'title']} key={'title' + index + Math.random()}>
                                <Input />
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={4}>
                            <Form.Item label='Type' name={[field.name, 'type']}>
                                <Radio.Group>
                                    <Radio value={'link'}>URL</Radio>
                                    <Radio value={'page'}>Page</Radio>
                                </Radio.Group>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={9}>
                            <Form.Item
                                noStyle
                                shouldUpdate={(prevValues, currentValues) =>
                                    prevValues?.menuTree?.[field.name]?.type !== currentValues?.menuTree?.[field.name]?.type
                                }
                            >
                                {({ getFieldValue }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            {getFieldValue(['menuTree', field.name, 'type']) === 'link' ? (
                                                <Form.Item name={[field.name, 'url']} label='URL'>
                                                    <Input />
                                                </Form.Item>
                                            ) : (
                                                <Form.Item name={[field.name, 'page']} label='Page'>
                                                    <Input />
                                                </Form.Item>
                                            )}
                                        </>
                                    );
                                }}
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={2}>
                            <Form.Item>
                                <Button htmlType='button' onClick={() => {}}>
                                    <CaretUpOutlined />
                                </Button>
                                <Button htmlType='button' onClick={() => {}}>
                                    <CaretDownOutlined />
                                </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={1}>
                            <Button htmlType='button' onClick={() => remove(field.name)}>
                                <MinusOutlined />
                            </Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                ))}
                <Button type='dashed' onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                    Add menu item
                </Button>
            </>
        )}
    </Form.List>
</Form>
```